# import types in python

Tags: python, import, module

I have a module named `types` which has the following code in it

```
def Hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

But when I do

```
>>> import types
>>> types.Hello()
```

It gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Hello'
```

This is really freaking me out.

Comment: Whats the path of your module? and how you run your code?

Comment: See carefully where you save your module, and this path can be put. Take a look to see can be import modules from other paths, for example to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`types` is a built-in module and `import` searches for a built-in module first before looking into local package.

```
>>> import types
>>> types
<module 'types' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc'>
```

Try

```
>>> from . import types
```

Comment: Or don't name your modules the same as built-in modules

Comment: True that! But only if you know such modules pre-exists

Comment: Good answer .. whenever you are creating a modules you should take care of the their is no modules with the same name existing in the python library .

Comment: `from . import types` only works from within a package; it's not an all-purpose technique for distinguishing between standard modules and locally defined ones.

Answer (score 5):

Actually `types` is a built-in module which doesn't provide a `Hello` function.If you want to create a costume module you need to put it in your python directory!

And note that the name of your module shouldn't be same as python built-in modules!

Answer (score 2):

Never name your module **same as** Python built-in modules, read [this section](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=intermezzo) and [Naming Convetion](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) to get a better idea.

> 4.8. Intermezzo: Coding Style
>
> For Python, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) has emerged as the style guide that most projects
> adhere to; it promotes a very readable and eye-pleasing coding style.
> Every Python developer should read it at some point; here are the most
> important points extracted for you:
>
> Name your classes and functions consistently; the convention is to use
> CamelCase for classes and lower_case_with_underscores for functions
> and methods. Always use self as the name for the first method argument
> (see A First Look at Classes for more on classes and methods).

Just posted from this section what's relevant to your issue.